# How can I use SHA-256 Certificate to generate XML Signature in .Net 2.0?

Tags: xml, .net-2.0, digital-signature, sha256, xml-signature

My application has a requirement to sign a XML document with a SHA-256 certificate. Previously application was based on .Net 4.5. So I used [this post](http://www.componentspace.com/Forums/30/SHA256-XML-Signature-Support) to achieve the requirement and it was working fine. But now there is a requirement to downgrade the application to use .Net 2.0.

Even second option in the above post is for the applications based on .Net 3.5 and above. How can I use SHA256RSA certificate to sign a XML document in .Net 2.0? At least is there any other library I can use?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but [the SHA256 class existed in .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256), so you should still be able to use it...

Comment: @WaiHaLee It probably that the combination SHA256 / RSA for signatures is not supported (for XML based signatures anyway). As DLK didn't answer or include code I'll close this question though.

Comment: @ WaiHaLee, Yes you are correct that SHA256 class exists in .Net 2.0. We can use that for computing SHA256 Hash. But we cannot use that for signing XMLs. During XML signing we use a certificate. This certificate is a  SHA256RSA one.